# Adding event to variable:

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add an event listener to a button variable? I am trying to increase like and dislike by one when the user clicks them.

```js
let result = '';
var like = '<button id="like">Like</button>';
var disLike = '<button id="disLike">Dislike</button>';
var flag = '<button id="flag">flag</button>';

result += '<ul>';
result += '<li style="padding:0;">Title: ' + data.title + '</li>';
result += '<li>' + data.story + '</li>';
result += '<li>Author: ' + data.Author + '</li>';
result += '<li>Author: ' + data.key + '</li>';
result += '<li>' + like + disLike + flag + '</li>';
result += '</ul>';

$('#stories').append(result);

});
});
var i = 0;
$('#like').click(function(i) {
  i++;
  alert(i);

});
```

Comment: Not sure where the `});
});` come from, but if you insert the button after you define the event handler, you need to delegate: `$('#stories').on("click","#like",function() { ....` and you cannot pass "i" to that function but instead pass the event to cancel it: `$('#stories').on("click","#like",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ....` - this will work for ONE button with id=like. If you have more than one, use a class

Comment: The event handler works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6pmqnr3v/. Admittedly there a few other issues, but the event is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options add click just after append, (NOTE: that you should have unique id, if you're adding more then one like button, use class instead)

```
$('#stories').append(result).find('#button').click(function(i){
    i++;
    alert(i);
});
```

second options is to using event delegation, you're adding click using `on()` function to element that always in DOM (page):

```
$('#stories').on('click', '.button', function() {
   i++;
   alert(i);
});
```

this will work if you'll add:

```
var like = '<button class="like">Like</button>';
var disLike = '<button class="disLike">Dislike</button>';
var flag = '<button class="flag">flag</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is construct the DOM in memory first instead of immediately putting it to `append`. That way, you can assign the handler before it's placed on the page DOM.

```
const html = '<ul><li><button id="like"></button></li></ul>'
const jQueryVersionOfHtml = $(html)

// Find element and attach handler
jQueryVersionOfHtml.find('#like').click(function() { ... })

// Then attach the HTML to the DOM
$('#stories').append(jQueryVersionOfHtml);
```

Alternatively, you can use delegation - a fancy way of saying "put the handler on an ancestor element". In this case, stories. This is achieved with `jquery.on()`.

```
// Put a click handler on #stories for #like.
$('#stories').on('click', '#like', function(){ ... })
```